# How to specify the github address for cargo's separate dependency？

Tags: rust-cargo

[image]

From Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies.filecoin-proofs-api]
package = "filecoin-proofs-api"
version = "5.4.1"
default-features = false
```

I use my own GitHub address, how to configure？

Comment: please to not include code/configurations as picture. Copy the text instead.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `version` with `git` in your configuration.

This is an example from https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html,

```
[dependencies]
rand = { git = "https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rand", branch = "next" }
```

Your example would look something like

```
[dependencies.filecoin-proofs-api]
package = "filecoin-proofs-api"
git = "ssh://git@github.com/filecoin-project/rust-filecoin-proofs-api.git"
default-features = false
```

Comment: `[dependencies.filecoin-proofs-api]
package = "filecoin-proofs-api"
version = "5.4.1"
default-features = false `

like this, How to configure this format?

l

Comment: Try this: `[dependencies] filecoin-proofs-api ={ git ="ssh://git@github.com/filecoin-proofs-api"  default-features = false }`

Comment: ths, maybe I’m too stubborn, I want to configure it in the `[dependencies.filecoin-proofs-api]` option property

Comment: got it, `git = "ssh://git@github.com/filecoin-project/rust-filecoin-proofs-api.git"`  this cmd, can checkout specify a branch?